# Upload a video to Youtube using Node.js using a stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I can easily update a video to Youtube:

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis');

googleapis.discover('youtube', 'v3').execute(function(err, client) {

var metadata = {
    snippet: { title:'title', description: 'description'}, 
    status: { privacyStatus: 'private' }
};

client
    .youtube.videos.insert({ part: 'snippet,status'}, metadata)
    .withMedia('video/mp4', fs.readFileSync('user.flv'))
    .withAuthClient(auth)
    .execute(function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, '  '));
    });
});
```

The problem is that for large files that `fs.readFileSync` is very un-practical.

Apparently [this was fixed](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/105) but the example provided is for Google Drive:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v2', auth: oauth2Client });

drive.files.insert({
  resource: {
    title: 'testimage.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    body: fs.createReadStream('awesome.png') // read streams are awesome!    
  }
}, callback);
```

How do I upload to Youtube using a stream?

Comment: Look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-youtube-resumable-upload

Comment: I am after something that uses the official module googleapis rather than calling the URLs directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I am able to upload using this module for large file(>2GB).

```
var youtube = require('googleapis').youtube('v3');

 youtube.videos.insert({
     'auth': auth,
     'resource': resource,
    'part': part,
     'media': fs.createReadStream(videoFilePath)
}, callback);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Is this a solution?